# Run multiple php scripts in sequence from a single php script or batch file in windows

Tags: php, shell, cron

I have 5 php scripts need to be executed one after other. How can i create a single php/batch script which executes all the php scripts in sequence.

I want to schedule a cron which run that php file.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/path/to/your/php
<?php
include("script1.php");
include("script2.php");
include("script3.php");
//...
?>
```

Alternative

```
#/bin/bash
/path/to/your/php /path/to/your/script1.php
/path/to/your/php /path/to/your/script2.php
/path/to/your/php /path/to/your/script3.php
# ...
```

If your scripts need to be accessed via http:

```
#/bin/bash
wget --quiet http://path/to/your/script1.php > /dev/null 2>&1
wget --quiet http://path/to/your/script2.php > /dev/null 2>&1
wget --quiet http://path/to/your/script3.php > /dev/null 2>&1
# ...
```

Comment: what about using exec?? instead of include as there may be some clashing of variables if i use include

Comment: If you keep your code clean there is no need to start more shell and php instances.

Comment: It's not a cleanliness issue ... it's a housekeeping issue, and it can be a pain in the neck making sure all your variables unique names if you don't want them treated globally, but that's what you have to do.  I kind of hate this about the include function.

Answer (score 1):

I did something for testing using the "wait" command, as it seems I just put wait between the calls to each script. I did a little test creating databases in php scripts, returning some records in a bash script, then updating with another php script, then another bash script to return the updated results and it seemed to work fine...

From what I have read, as long as the subscript doesn't call another subscript, the master script will wait if "wait" command is used between script calls.

Code is as below:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/php test.php
wait

/bin/bash test.sh
wait

/usr/bin/php test2.php
wait

/bin/bash test2.sh
wait

echo all done
```

Hope it would execute all the php scripts in sequence.